# Curvature as infinitesimal holonomy

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

Let $P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle, assume as much regularity as you want (compact $G$ or compact base manifold, ect). Via parallel transport, a connection $A$ on $P$ gives rise to the holonomy map
$$
Hol_p: L_m M \to G
$$
where $p \in P$ is a chosen reference point projecting on $m \in M$ and $L_mM$ denotes the loop group based at $m$ (i.e piecewise smooth, closed curves starting at $m$).

> Question: What is the exact relationship between the curvature $F_A$ of $A$ and the derivative of $Hol_p$ at the constant loop (the infinitesimal holonomy).

In the abelian case, I can answer this question as follows:
Let $\gamma_s$ be a family of loops which represent a tangential vector $X \in T_\gamma L_mM$, that is $\gamma_0 = \gamma$ and $\frac{d}{ds}{\big|_0} \gamma_s = X$. Then the derivative of $Hol_p$ in the direction of $X$ evaluates to
$$
\frac{d}{ds}{\big|_0} Hol_p (\gamma_s) = \frac{d}{ds}{\big|_0} \exp (\int_{\gamma_s} A) = (\exp)'_0 \int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds}{\big|_0} A(\dot \gamma_s(t)) dt = \int_0^1 dA(\frac{d}{ds}{\big|_0} \gamma_s(t), \dot \gamma_0(t)) dt,
$$
That is, in this case we get a close expression for the derivative of $Hol_p$ at an arbitary loop $\gamma$ in terms of the curvature $F_A = dA$. Furthermore, the Ambrose-Singer theorem follows from this expression.

I was hoping to get a similar result also for the non-abelian case.

Sidequestion: conjugacy classes of (topological) homomorphisms $h$ between the loop gorup and $G$ uniquely determine a equivalence class of principal bundles with curvature by a result of Kobayashi (1954). Which additional properties on $h$ have to be impsoed to characterize all (equivalence classes of) connections on a *fixed* principal bundle $P$.

Comment: The answer is given by the Ambrose-Singer theorem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose.E2.80.93Singer_theorem

Comment: See pages  99-100 of these notes  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: Thanks abx for the reference to the Ambrose-Singer theorem. I see the close relationship between my question and this theorem, but I think the derivative of the holonomy is even a stronger result. I updated my question to better clarify my idea and the intuition one gets from the abelian case. @ Liviu: Thank you for the link! This goes in the direction I had in mind. Do you know why one can restrict ones attention to a small parallelogram and does not consider arbitrary small loops?

Comment: These kinds of questions are discussed here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0452 , also http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0663 .

Comment: I am still trying to understand what could be the notion of smooth map here... I searched in google  for smoothness of holonomy map anf first result mentioned is about your seminar https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/de/node/7584 Can you make notes of that seminar (if there are any) public? Or can I contact you on email to get notes?

Comment: The paper Parallel transport on Principal bundles over stacks by Collier, Lerman and Wolbert also says something about smoothness of the map by using the notion of "diffeological group"..

Comment: @abx the description in the A-S theorem in the link is weaker than what OP is asking.

Comment: Relevant pages in the link provided by @LiviuNicolaescu are updated to (114-117) as of today. Future user might search for the subsection "holonomy". Liviu: can the heuristic explanation of curvature 2-form be extended before taking limit? I hope a stronger version holds: the holonomy along a (non-infinitestimal) loop is the integration of the curvature two form over a surface bounded by the loop.

Comment: A calculus level proof of that curvature = holonomy can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311322/alternative-easier-proof-of-ambrose-singer-holonomy-theorem), in Deane Yang's answer.

Comment: @Student Here is how a proof would go to see where it gets stuck. Take a contour $C$ bounding a surface $S$.Subdivide the surface using a fine grid. The holonomy along a tiny  rectangle of the grid is well approximated by the curvature at one of the vertices. But you have to be careful: the holonomy is an element of a Lie group while curvature is in the Lie algebra.If the groupis noncommutative you need to be very careful with the integration.You are not adding elements in the Lie algebra, you are multiplying elements of a possibly noncommutative group

Comment: Makes sense.. this worries me about the correctness of the proof in the above link..

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I draw pictures and think more carefully today. Sure, if each oriented little square $sq_i$ contribute a group difference $g_i$, over a 2D surface we can not just "add" all $g_i$ together. However, in each case I tried, there's always an order that makes sense. In summary, I think integrating a $Lie(G)$-valued 2-form over an oriented surface makes sense, even for nonabelian G.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea about the sidequestion. For the main question, there is a general answer applicable for any parallel transport, not only for holonomy.

Let $\gamma_{s}$ a family of smooth paths such that $\gamma_{s}(0)=p,\gamma_{s}(1)=q$ for every $s$ and fixed points $p$, $q$, and let $P_{s}(t’,t)$ the parallel transport from $\gamma_{s}(t)$ to $\gamma_{s}(t’)$ along $\gamma_{s}$. Here I try to prove the formula

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{ds}P_s(1,0)= \int_{0}^{1}P_{s}(1,t)F(\partial_{t}\gamma_{s}(t),\partial_{s}\gamma_{s}(t))P_{s}(t,0)dt
\end{equation},
$$

where $F$ is the curvature. (There might appear a negative sign depending on convention. I use a convention where $F=dA+A\wedge A, \nabla=d+A, F(w,v)=F_{\nu\mu}w^{\nu}v^{\mu}$.) Especially if $\gamma_{0}$ is the constant loop, then $\partial_{t}\gamma_{0}(t)$ is always zero, so the derivative map of $Hol_{p}$ at the constant loop is just the zero map.

The proof goes as if we are discussing a connection of vector bundles. Let $H_{t}(s’,s)$ the parallel transport from $\gamma_{s}(t)$ to $\gamma_{s’}(t)$ along $\gamma_{\bullet}(t)$ and let $S(s,s’;t)=P_{s}(1,t)H_{t}(s,s’)P_{s’}(t,0)$. Then,

$$
P_{s’}(1,0)-P_{s}(1,0)=S(s,s’;1)-S(s,s’;0)
=\int_{0}^{1}\partial_{t}S(s,s’;t)dt
=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} P_s(1,t+\epsilon)\frac{H_{t+\epsilon}(s,s’)P_{s’}(t+\epsilon,t)-P_{s}(t+\epsilon,t)H_{t}(s,s’)}{\epsilon}P_{s’}(t,0)dt,
$$

so

$$
\partial_{s}P_{s}(1,0)=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{(\epsilon,\delta)\rightarrow 0}P_{s}(1,t+\epsilon)\frac{H_{t+\epsilon}(s,s+\delta)P_{s+\delta}(t+\epsilon,t)-P_{s}(t+\epsilon,t)H_{t}(s,s+\delta)}{\epsilon\delta}P_{s+\delta}(t,0)dt.
$$

From the parallelogram discussion follows the identity

$$
\lim_{(\epsilon,\delta)\rightarrow 0} \frac{H_{t+\epsilon}(s,s+\delta)P_{s+\delta}(t+\epsilon,t)-P_{s}(t+\epsilon,t)H_{t}(s,s+\delta)}{\epsilon\delta}=F(\partial_{t}\gamma_{s}(t),\partial_{s}\gamma_{s}(t)),
$$

and thus also does the formula I’m proving.

I’d like to comment that integrating both sides of the formula reads a relationship between $P_{s’}(1,0)-P_{s}(1,0)$ and the curvature, if we focus on connections of vector bundles. (If you want to discuss a $G$-principal bundle $Q$, you should remember that each $P_{s}(1,0)$ can be canonically identified with an element of $(Q_{q}\times Q_{p}\times G)/\sim$, where $(v,u,g)\sim(vy,ux,y^{-1}gx)$. Then the formula I have shown describes the path $P_{\bullet}(1,0)$ in this manifold in terms of the curvature.)

Comment: Maybe it’s better to formulate the parallelogram discussion as $\left(P_{s}(t,t+\epsilon)H_{t+\epsilon}(s,s+\delta)P_{s+\delta}(t+\epsilon,t)H_{t}(s+\delta,s)-1\right)/\epsilon\delta\rightarrow F(\partial_{t}\gamma,\partial_{s}\gamma)$. The proof can be easily modified. Some expressions in the process will become a little longer.

Comment: Hi, did you come up with this proof yourself or can I find it also elsewhere?