# Curvature as infinitesimal holonomy 2

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

This question may be seen as a follow up of [this original question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154863/25590). I'm learning Cheeger-Simons differential characters (reading *Differential Characters* of Bär and Becker).
If I understand correctly, the idea is based on the fact that something like this is true:

Let $P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle where $G = U(1)$ and let $\omega$ be a connection in $P$. Denote by $F_\omega \in \Omega^2(M, \mathfrak{g}_P)$ the curvature of $\omega$.

Let $S \subseteq M$ be an oriented $2$-dimensional submanifold with boundary $\gamma = \partial S$. Then
$$\mathit{hol}_\omega (\gamma) = \exp\left(\int_S F_\omega\right) \in G\,.$$

(In the book, there is $2i\pi$ in front of the integral, but I guess it's because they choose an identification $\mathfrak{u}(1) \approx \mathbb{R}$).

Why is this identity true? Does some version of this hold for more general $G$? If that were the case, it would seem like a better version of Ambrose-Singer / a pretty good answer to [the original question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154863/25590).

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated, the formula is not true (even up to some normalisation factor). Consider a connection $d+\omega$ on a complex line bundle, where $\omega\in\Omega^1(M,\mathbb C).$ The curvature is just $d\omega$, and the parallel transport along a curve $\gamma$ is just $exp(-\int_\gamma\omega)$. Thus, if you can apply Stokes theorem you can derive the holonomy formula. But this is not always the case, as you see from the example of the punctured disc (with boundary $S^1$) and the flat connection $d+a\frac{dz}{z}.$

There is no direct generalisation to non-abelian Lie groups $G$. For example, there exists flat $SU(2)$-connections on the 1-holed torus with non-trivial monodromy along the boundary.

Comment: I don't understand: first you provide a "proof" that the formula is true, and then you contradict yourself? The problem with the puncture seems inessential, obviously Stokes doesn't work stricto sensu for noncompact manifolds, so I assume same goes for the formula. Feel free to assume S is compact is my post.

Comment: The formula is not true for general surfaces $S$. But  if you consider a compact oriented surface $S$ with non-trivial boundary, you can trivialise  the principal $S^1$ bundle. This defines a connection 1-form on $S$, also called  $\omega$ by abuse of notation, and Stokes theorem gives the holonomy formula. In the case of a closed orientable  surface the formula holds as the degree of the $S^1$ bundle is an integer.

Comment: In other words, the formula *is* true for general oriented surfaces $S$ with or without boundary, as long as they're compact.